# Typo3 - access image of content element on a different page?

Tags: php, typo3, fluid

I am working on a typo3 v. 10.4.13 site. What I would likt to achieve is this: I have a page with custom content elements and want to list some information of these elements on a different page. The content element stores some text an integer values and an image. What I got so far is, that I can access all text and integers: I use vhs viewhelper's v:content.get to  get the other page's object and find the requested information in the 'pi_flexform' field as xml. I wrote me a  custom viewhelper with some simple php that converts me this in an associative array which I can use in fluid. (Maybe there is a much easier way to do this?)

But my main problem is: I haven't found out how to access the element's image. vhs returns me only am integer in the 'image' field (probably no the image id - it's always 1 or 0) and the same value in the pi_flexform field xml. How/where does typo3 store the information which image to use with the element? How can I access this information? Sorry if this is a stupid question - I don't have much experience with typo3 yet. Many thanks for any help in advance!

The content element's xml definition for the image field is:

```
<navpic>
    <TCEforms>
        <label>Image</label>
        <config>
            <type>inline</type>
            <maxitems>1</maxitems>
            <foreign_table>sys_file_reference</foreign_table>
            <foreign_table_field>tablenames</foreign_table_field>
            <foreign_label>uid_local</foreign_label>
            <foreign_sortby>sorting_foreign</foreign_sortby>
            <foreign_field>uid_foreign</foreign_field>
            <foreign_selector>uid_local</foreign_selector>
            <foreign_selector_fieldTcaOverride>
                <config>
                    <appearance>
                        <elementBrowserType>file</elementBrowserType>
                        <elementBrowserAllowed>gif,jpg,jpeg,png,svg</elementBrowserAllowed>
                    </appearance>
                </config>
            </foreign_selector_fieldTcaOverride>
            <foreign_types type="array">
                <numIndex index="0">
                    <showitem>--palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,--palette--;;filePalette</showitem>
                </numIndex>
                <numIndex index="2">
                    <showitem>--palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,--palette--;;filePalette</showitem>
                </numIndex>
            </foreign_types>
            <foreign_match_fields>
                <fieldname>image</fieldname>
            </foreign_match_fields>
            <appearance type="array">
                <newRecordLinkAddTitle>1</newRecordLinkAddTitle>
                <headerThumbnail>
                    <field>uid_local</field>
                    <height>64</height>
                    <width>64</width>
                </headerThumbnail>
                <enabledControls>
                    <info>1</info>
                    <new>0</new>
                    <dragdrop>0</dragdrop>
                    <sort>1</sort>
                    <hide>0</hide>
                    <delete>1</delete>
                    <localize>1</localize>
                </enabledControls>
                <createNewRelationLinkTitle>LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:images.addFileReference
                                    </createNewRelationLinkTitle>
            </appearance>
            <behaviour>
                <localizationMode>select</localizationMode>
                <localizeChildrenAtParentLocalization>1</localizeChildrenAtParentLocalization>
            </behaviour>
            <overrideChildTca>
                <columns type="array">
                    <uid_local type="array">
                        <config type="array">
                            <appearance type="array">
                                <elementBrowserType>file</elementBrowserType>
                                <elementBrowserAllowed>gif,jpg,jpeg,png,svg</elementBrowserAllowed>
                            </appearance>
                        </config>
                    </uid_local>
                </columns>
                <types type="array">
                    <numIndex index="2">
                        <showitem>--palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,--palette--;;filePalette </showitem>
                    </numIndex>
                </types>
            </overrideChildTca>
        </config>
    </TCEforms>
</navpic>
```

Answer (score 0):

Oehm... Why do you define content via flexform? tt_content has a column for images (and if this is already used, you can extend the table).

After this change, it should be possible to collect the desired data via DataProcessors.

Basics for both can be found here:
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/ContentElements/AddingYourOwnContentElements.html